# Write to Python file with different fonts

Tags: python, python-2.7, fonts, save

I need to write one line of formatted text to a `*.rtf` file with Python. If I tried to print this line, here is how I would do it in Python:

```
print Kelvin of %s sensor at C is %s K, recorded with command p -V2 bery.org. % (MAC,210)
```

However, I need to write this single line to a file using formatted output placeholder `%s`.

When writing this line to a file:

1. I need the word MAC to be printed in the `Consolas` font.
2. I need all other text on the line to be printed in `Arial` font.

Is this possible with Python (on Windows)?

Comment: Did you google it? First result: http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.html

Comment: Thanks but it doesn;t seem to be printing with a placeholder `%s` which I am having trouble with. If the whole line is one font, then I can do it. I just need a few words to be of different font BUT I need those same words to be printed using variables.

Comment: Perhaps this will help then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401902/setting-font-style-for-rtf-document Set the default font to Arial and create a font which you then use around the correct %s in your example.

Comment: Yup got it! Thanks. That works. This Question has been answered.